# Non-examples of area preserving map

Tags: dynamical-systems

I am trying to understand the maps which are area-preserving and maps which are not. 
I know that the standard map is an area-preserving map since the Jacobian determinant is 1.

I also know that for the maps which the area is not preserved, they belong to the dissipative system (in contrast of Hamiltonian system).

Can anybody gives example of 2-d mapping that is not area-preserving map?

Comment: What about $(x,y)\to (2x,2y)$?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

You  can use any linear map with determinant different from $\pm 1$.

Answer (score 1):

If $U$ is a non-empty open subset of the plane, a continuously-differentiable mapping $f:U \to U$ is area-preserving if and only if $|\det Df| = 1$.

A "randomly-chosen" plane mapping is not area-preserving. Among holomorphic mappings, for example, the only area-preserving examples are affine mappings $f(z) = \alpha z + \beta$ with $|\alpha| = 1$.

More interesting is the fact the space of area-preserving mappings is infinite-dimensional. If $\phi$ is a continuously-differentiable real-valued function of one variable, for example, the mapping
$$
f(x, y) = (x, y + \phi(x))
$$
is area-preserving, as is the mapping given in polar coordinates by
$$
f(r, \theta) = (r, \theta + \phi(r)).
$$